# SQL Insert with large dataset

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When running a query like "insert into table " how do we handle the commit size? I.e. are all records from anotherTable inserted in a single transaction OR is there a way to set a commit size?

<s>Thanks very much ~Sri</s>
 <s>PS: I am a first timer here, and this site looks very good!</s>

Comment: For newbies, Please try to avoid adding unnecessary elements to the question. Make use of the comment section (frugally) for the same. :) Bit by Bit makes a byte.

Answer (score 3):

In good databases that is an atomic statement, so no, there is no way to limit the number of records inserted - which is a good thing!

Answer (score 3):

In the context that the original poster wants to avoid rollback space problems, the answer is pretty straightforward. The rollback segments should be sized to accpomodate the size of transactions, not the other way round. You commit when your transaction is complete.

Answer (score 2):

I've written code in various langues, mostly Java, to do bulk inserts like what you described.  Each time I did it, mostly from parsing some input file or something like that, I would basically just prepare a sub-set of data to insert from the total amount (usually batches of 4000 or so) and feed that data to our DAO layer.  So it was done programatically.  We never noticed any real performance hit for doing it this way and we were dealing with a few million records.  If you have large data sets to insert the operation will "take awhile" regardless of how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle the commit size unless you explicitly code it. For example you could use a where loop, and code up a way to limit the ammount of data your selecting.

Comment: but with large inserts this is usually sub-optimal.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is getting down-voted as it's correct.

Comment: Me neither nick never understand it.

Answer (score 1):

David Aldridge is right, size the rollback segment based on the maximum transaction, when you want the INSERT to either succeed or fail as a whole.

Some alternatives:

If you don't care about being able to roll it back (which is what the segment is there for), you could ALTER TABLE and add the **NOLOGGING** clause.  But that's not a wise move unless you're loading a reporting table where you drop all old rows and load new ones, or some other special cases.

If you're okay with some rows getting inserted and others failing for some reason, then add support for handling the failures, using the *INSERT INTO* **LOG ERRORS INTO** syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data set to be limited, build that limit into the query.

For example, in Microsoft SQL Server parlance, you can use "`TOP` *`N`*" to make sure the query only returns a limited number of rows.

```
INSERT INTO thisTable
  SELECT TOP 100 * FROM anotherTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I want to do that is to avoid the rollback segment going out of space. Also, I want to see results being populated in the target table at regular intervals.

I dont want to use a where loop because it might add performance overheads. Isn't it?

~Sri

Comment: You should tag your question with "oracle" since IIRC the rollback segment is an Oracle feature.

Comment: I believe the expected approach on this site is that you should edit your original question with any further information, as it could potentially get lost as other answers are voted up.

Comment: Can you add this as a modification to the original question?

Comment: @sri This isn't an answer, this should be a comment or edit on your original question

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you may want to run large inserts in batches. The attached link shows a way to do it in SQL Server, if you are using a different backend you would do something simliar but the exact syntax might be differnt. This is a case when a loop is acceptable.

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3141

Answer (score 0):

"The reason why I want to do that is to avoid the rollback segment going out of space. Also, I want to see results being populated in the target table at regular intervals."

The first is simply a matter of sizing the undo tablespace correctly. Since the undo is a delete of an existing row, it doesn't require a lot of space. Conversely, a delete generally requires more space because it has to have a copy of the entire deleted row to re-insert it to undo it.

For the second, have a look at v$session_longops and/or rows_processed in v$sql

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableInserted
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT  *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
   FROM TableSelected
) X
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 101 AND 200
```

You could wrap the above into a while loop pretty easily, replacing the 101 and 200 with variables. It's better than doing 1 record at a time.

I don't know what versions of Oracle support window functions.

Comment: -1 because this is a horribly slow approach. For a 100,000 record table you are accessing "TableSelected" 1000 times, and each access likely is a full table scan ...

Comment: You're assuming that it's always a table scan.  okay, put the data in a temp table.

Where's your better way?  Don't see it in here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment to demonstrate that setting indexes to NOLOGGING will *not* help reduce UNDO or REDO for INSERTs.

The manual implies NOLOGGING indexes may help improve DML by reducing UNDO and REDO.  And since NOLOGGING helps with table DML it seems logical that it would also help with INDEX changes.  But this test case demonstrates that changing indexes to NOLOGGING has no affect on INSERT statements.

```
drop table table_no_index;
drop table table_w_log_index;
drop table table_w_nolog_index;

--#0: Before
select name, value from v$mystat natural join v$statname where display_name in ('undo change vector size', 'redo size') order by 1;

--#1: NOLOGGING table with no index.  This is the best case scenario.
create table table_no_index(a number) nologging;
insert /*+ append */ into table_no_index select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
select name, value from v$mystat natural join v$statname where display_name in ('undo change vector size', 'redo size') order by 1;

--#2: NOLOGGING table with LOGGING index.  This should generate REDO and UNDO.
create table table_w_log_index(a number) nologging;
create index table_w_log_index_idx on table_w_log_index(a);
insert /*+ append */ into table_w_log_index select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
select name, value from v$mystat natural join v$statname where display_name in ('undo change vector size', 'redo size') order by 1;

--#3: NOLOGGING table with NOLOGGING index.  Does this generate as much REDO and UNDO as previous step?
create table table_w_nolog_index(a number) nologging;
create index table_w_nolog_index_idx on table_w_nolog_index(a) nologging;
insert /*+ append */ into table_w_nolog_index select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
select name, value from v$mystat natural join v$statname where display_name in ('undo change vector size', 'redo size') order by 1;
```

Here are the results from the statistics queries.  The numbers are cumulative for the session.  Test cases #2 and #3 have the same increase in UNDO and REDO.

```
--#0: BEFORE: Very little redo or undo since session just started.
redo size      35,436
undo change vector size    10,120

--#1: NOLOGGING table, no index: Very little redo or undo.
redo size      88,460
undo change vector size    21,772

--#2: NOLOGGING table, LOGGING index: Large amount of redo and undo.
redo size   6,895,100
undo change vector size 3,180,920

--#3: NOLOGGING table, NOLOGGING index: Large amount of redo and undo.
redo size   13,736,036
undo change vector size 6,354,032
```

Answer (score -1):

You may just want to make the indexes NOLOGGING.  That way the table data is recoverable, but the indexes will need to be rebuilt if table is recovered.  Index maintenance can create a lot of undo.

Comment: Unfortunately index NOLOGGING only applies when [creating an index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF54007).

Comment: @jonearles, from the documentation you linked, "This setting also determines whether subsequent ... direct-path INSERT operations against the index are logged or not logged."  You can use the append hint to get direct path inserts.

Comment: Good point, I should have read my link more closely!  But I still think it is accurate to say NOLOGGING only applies when creating or rebuilding an index.  In [this AskTom thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869#1122618100346323255) Tom says the same thing several times.  Some other online sources, and my simple tests, also agree that NOLOGGING doesn't reduce index redo during direct path inserts.  I submitted a comment for the documentation, although I'm not sure if that will ever do any good.

Comment: I was talking about reducing undo.  From that same AskTom thread: "The undo will be minimized for the index but has to be generated ..."https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869#2792776900346480651 What wasn't clear from that quote is the effect of NOLOGGING on the index.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to help with UNDO either.  See my answer/comment below.  I'm not sure *why* it doesn't help, it would be a very useful feature if it worked.